# Unable to Set PivotTable to Workbook Connection (ACCESS DB)

Tags: excel, connection-string, pivot-table, vba

**Goal**: to connect my Pivot Table directly to the source DB table (in MS-ACCESS 2010).

**Status**: I am able to set up the `WorkbookConnection` to the DB via VBA.
I am also able to create the `PivotTable` by using the code:

```
WB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=Conn) _
                .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), _
                TableName:="OnePager"
```

However, trying to `Set PvtTbl` with the 2 options below produces a Run-Time Error (1004):

*Option 1*:

```
Set PvtTbl = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), TableName:="OnePager")
```

*Option 2*:

```
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("ManHours").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), TableName:="OnePager")
```

**My Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dynamic_PivotTable()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WBConns As WorkbookConnection
Dim Conn    As WorkbookConnection
Dim ConnString As String

Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache    As PivotCache

Set WB = Workbooks("DynamicPivot_Connection.xlsm") '<-- Workbook is open

' define ConnectionString
ConnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=J:\PMO\Resource allocation\DB\Resource_DB.accdb;" & _
            "Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False"

' loop through all Workbook connections and delete all except "Resource_DB"
For Each WBConns In WB.Connections
    Select Case WBConns.Name
        Case "Resource_DB"
            Set Conn = WBConns
        Case Else
            WBConns.Delete        
    End Select
Next WBConns

If Conn Is Nothing Then
    Set Conn = WB.Connections.Add("Resource_DB", "Resource DB Full Data Set", ConnString, "Select * from MergedDBTbl", 3)
End If

' set the Pivot Cache to update Workbook connection
Set PvtCache = WB.PivotCaches.Add(xlExternal, Conn)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("ManHours").PivotTables("OnePager") ' check if "OnePager" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "ManHours" sheet, start from Cell A1                   
    WB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=Conn) _
                .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), TableName:="OnePager"

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Pivot" sheet, start from Cell A1  ******* LINE BELOW PRODUCES AN ERROR ******
    Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("ManHours").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), TableName:="OnePager")


    ' ******* LINE BELOW PRODUCES AN ERROR ******
    Set PvtTbl = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Worksheets("ManHours").Range("A1"), TableName:="OnePager")
     'Create the headings and row and column orientation and all of your other settings here

Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in "ManHours" worksheet)
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache  '<--- ALSO PRODUCES AN ERROR !
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look here - https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables - the guy uses pvtCache to create the PivotTable - `Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable`. Not sure whether it would work with you.

Comment: Are you running those lines sequentially?

Comment: @Rory ofcourse not, I comment each time 2 of them and try the 3rd. Only one works, but it's not the method I want to use.

Comment: @Vityata I'm familiar with this method, I've been able to work with PivotTables in the past quite successfully, but that was connecting to Data sources in Excel. Now I want to connect through a `Connection` to MS-ACCESS, and so far failing miserably

Comment: You should be using: `Set PvtCache = WB.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal, Conn)` rather than `Add`

Comment: @Rory thanks:) that did the first part. How do I now `PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache` ? or refresh the PivotTable everytime the ACCESS DB is modified

Comment: Access doesn't do triggers, so you'd be better off either refreshing on a schedule or just when the workbook is opened, or the sheet activated, depending on how live you need it to be.

Comment: @Rory OK, so let's say I Do it on `Workbook_Open` event, how do I refresh the `PivotTable` ?

Comment: You can just set the pivot cache to do that automatically when you create it by setting its `RefreshOnFileOpen` property to True.

Comment: @Rory thanks a lot ! please post as answer so I can accept it. I waisted half a day on this, and would have more without your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using:

```
Set PvtCache = WB.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal, Conn)
```

rather than:

```
Set PvtCache = WB.PivotCaches.Add(xlExternal, Conn)
```

And to make the pivot table refresh automatically when the workbook is opened, use:

```
PvtCache.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
```